# Is there a better solution in Python for this problem? Thanks

Tags: python

Given an array of scores sorted in increasing order, return true if the array contains 3 adjacent scores that differ from each other by at most 2, such as with {3, 4, 5} or {3, 5, 5}.
Examples

```
scoresClump([3, 4, 5]) → true
scoresClump([3, 4, 6]) → false
scoresClump([1, 3, 5, 5]) → true
```

A solution below here seems to work but Translating it into Python looks tricky.

```
function scoresClump(scores) {
for (let i = 0; i < scores.length - 1; i++) {
if (scores[i + 2] - scores[i] <= 2) {
  return true;
}
}
return false;
```

}

I have tried this in Python and it keeps going out of range or giving the wrong output.

```
arr=[1,3, 5, 5]
i=0
while i<(len(arr)-1):
if (arr[i+2]-arr[i])<=2 and (arr[i+1]-arr[i])<=2:
 print("True")
 i=i+1  
else:  
 print("False")
 break
```

Comment: why not compare `max(scores`) and `min(scores)` and check if the difference is <= 2

Comment: Your javascript (not java) solution also accesses the array out of bounds. But aside from fixing the array out-of-bounds, why is your python solution so different from the javascript version? If you've had the insight about only needing one comparison not two (because the array is sorted), and the good idea to use a function, why have you forgotten these things when writing the Python version?

Comment: a more pythonic way would be `diff1 = [arr[i+2]-arr[i] for i in range(0,len(arr)-2)]`. This code would build this list given your example : `[4, 2]`

Comment: I do understand your logic but this may not work with this one [3, 3, 7, 7, 9], which should be True.

Comment: Stack Overflow should bring back the ban on the word ‘problem’ in question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this following function -

```
def scoresClump(nums):
    for x in range(2, len(nums)):
        if nums[x] - nums[x-2] <= 2:
            return True
    return False
```

if you want a one-liner using `any()` -

```
def scoresClump(nums):
    return any(nums[x] - nums[x-2] <= 2 for x in range(2, len(nums)))
```

```
>>> scoresClump([3, 4, 5])
True
>>> scoresClump([3, 4, 6])
False
>>> scoresClump([3, 4, 5, 5])
True
>>> scoresClump([3, 4])
False
>>> scoresClump([3])
False
>>> scoresClump([3, 3, 7, 7, 9])
True
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the logic behind it. But does not seem to work with scoresClump([3, 3, 7, 7, 9]) which should be true.

Comment: @user18127162 For `[3, 3, 7, 7, 9]`, the first set of 3 values would be `(3,3,7)`, with max difference being 4, which is more than 2, so we return `False`. Or do you want the function to return `True` as long as there exists a set of 3 values for which difference is less than 2?

Comment: The logic is backwards in the loop - this one is True if _every_ triple has values within 2 of each other, while you call for True if _any_ triple has values within 2 of each other.

Comment: Spot on Jack. Any triple that has a value difference <=2 of each other, returns true.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating until `i < len(arr)-1`, but you're reaching for `arr[i+2]`, which is out of range.

In Python you usually do *not* need to use an index variable. As you've seen they're a source of errors, and Python offers cleaner syntax without using them. For instance:

```py
# unpythonic
for i in range(len(scores)):
    print(scores[i])

# pythonic
for score in scores:
    print(score)
```

`zip` combines two (or more) things you can iterate over.
`scores[2:]` means "the `scores` list, but discarding the first two values".

```
scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for a, b in zip(scores, scores[2:]):
    print(a, b)
# 1 3
# 2 4
# 3 6
# zip then ends because it reached the end of scores[2:]
```

So, you can use `zip` and list slicing to compare the list with itself without index variables:

```py
def scores_clump(scores):
    for a, b in zip(scores, scores[2:]):
        if b - a <= 2:
            return True
    return False


scores_clump([1, 3, 4, 5])
# 4 - 1 is not <= 2
# 5 - 3 is <= 2, return True

scores_clump([1, 3, 6, 7, 9])
# 6 - 1 is not <= 2
# 7 - 3 is not <= 2
# 9 - 6 is not <= 2
# reached end of loop with no match, return False

scores_clump([3, 3, 7, 7, 9])
# 7 - 3 is not <= 2
# 7 - 3 is not <= 2
# 9 - 7 is <= 2, return True
```

Taking a leaf from Max's answer, you can reduce it further using `any`:

```
def scores_clump(scores):
    return any(b - a <= 2 for a, b in zip(scores, scores[2:]))
```

Comment: The array is sorted, so `max(a, b, c) - min(a, b, c)` is simply `c - a`. Thus you don't need `b` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement will reach arr[:-1] and then try and check two elements ahead of that, which don't exist, therefore going out of range. Rather than a while loop I would try something like this:

```
for x in range(0, len(arr)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a "sliding window" problem where window size=3 and we keep iterating over the array until we find a window where difference between adjacent elements is less than or equal to 2.

Here we can simply check if difference between last and first element of the window is <=2 or not because we are given a sorted array.

```
def scoresClump(array):
  for i in range(2,len(array)):
    if array[i]-array[i-2]<=2:
      return True
  return False

print(scoresClump([1, 3, 5, 5]))
```